# Get PTP time slippage between two differents devices PTP master

Tags: switches

I have two GPS antenna pluged on two diferents PTP switch. Each switch are configured how grandmaster.

My ideia is create two different time references synchronized.

I need to know how I validate a possible time slippage between each PTP switch.

Each switch has a high precision time (ns), but I need to know a slippage with milliseconds precision.

Comment: Are you looking at the PPS signal what are you using to look at it with a microcontroller with the timer?

Comment: Can you post your network block diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of PTP is to have just one grandmaster clock, and all the rest of the systems synch to it. GPS by itself will introduce jitter between 2 receivers - Even with good reception, you should expect ~100nsec of jitter.